# Call object of one controller in another controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and want to count num rows of "birthday" controller in "dailyattendance" controller.

birthday controller:

```
$data['query'] = $this->birthday_model->get_birthdate();
                $this->template->set_layout('users')->build('birthday',isset($data) ? $data : NULL); 

                $this->load->view('birthday',$data);
```

dailyattendance controller:

```
$this->load->module('modules/birthday');
                    $res = $this->birthday();
                    //$dataquery = $this->model->birthday_model();

                    if($res->row()->count > 0)
                    {
                        redirect('/birthday');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        redirect('');
                    }
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  If `birthday` and `dailyattendance` are different controllers, then they cannot call each other's methods.  You should but "common" methods in a helper/library (or even in the model).

Comment: @thnks Racket Hazmat, but I am using HMVC as I think it is possible to call each other's method.